# background image and size of the screen: how to do it correctly?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, background

How to well display a background image no matter what the size of the screen is?

Is there a preferred image size to work with?

I'm trying the new CSS3 background size attributes (cover) but I can't get a result that works well with small and big screens. I also tried different media queries but it did not work.

Do I have to create several versions of the image for different screens?

Small screen
[image]

Big screen
[image]

As you can see, on a big screen, it is like it is zoomed in so it does not display the main part of the picture anymore.

How to fix this?

The image comes from [unsplash](https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1424709746721-b8fd0ff52499?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=d58f9c4ae369aea0d2c7e4be03d6dcf6) and I did not resize it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that your background area has an aspect ratio of almost `4:1` which is very wide. The picture however has an aspect ratio of almost `4:3`.

This is why it becomes a problem in bigger screens. The picture just isn't wide enough.

There are different solutions to this, you could for example have the picture stretch to fit any width. But that might not be the desired behavior.

This is what I would do:

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/cq7ta2sp/1) - try resizing window to see behavior.

```
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-image: url('...');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

The `background-size: cover` property sets the picture to always fit it's entire width inside the container (though height will be cut off if it doesn't fit).

The `background-position: 50% 50%` sets the background to always be centered. This way, if the background cuts off, you will still see the center of the picture which is probably the most interesting portion of the picture.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it works better with this picture but I tried with another one and it is not that good: https://jsfiddle.net/yamikep/f3cutz8y/1/ So the issue is mainly that the dimension of those pictures are not appropriate for the dimension of the area correct? I would have to find/make the picture wider by maybe using a gradient on each side to fill the empty space if that is even possible without looking weird..?

Comment: It depends on the picture. The picture with the horse is a very zoomed-in picture by default, so it would always be hard to use as a background. However, if you want as much of the horse be visible, you can instead use `background-position: 50% 100%`. That will set the position to the bottom. [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/f3cutz8y/2/) try that

Comment: If you want, you can read more about the `background-position` property on [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp)

Comment: Thanks for the help.